# Invert Map | Values ---> Keys

Tags: java, dictionary, inverse

I want to be able to inverse a given HashMap that has multiple keys can point to the same value.

```
HashMap<String, String> cities = new HashMap<String, String>();

        cities.put("Manchester", "UK");
        cities.put("London", "UK");
```

```
static HashMap<String, String> inverseMap(HashMap map) {
       // something that has "UK" point to both "Manchester" and "London"

      // if it can be done without using any special Java 8 feature, that would be great
}
```

I am unsure where to start.

Comment: What do you mean by inverse a HashMap?

Comment: When you create a map with key -> value, I want to be able to take a given map and create a new one where value - > key. In my case, I want it to work where multiple keys point to a single value, so printed inverse will print all the keys that are linked to a single value.

Comment: What you're asking for goes against the basic idea of a map.  I think the best you can do with a "reverse map" in this case is to have a Map<String, List<String>> so that for your data you'd have a single entry of "UK" with a list of ["Manchester", "London"]

Comment: @Ryan That is exactly what I wanted. I dunno why but that didn't come into my head, but it is what I was looking for. Cheers, dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this. Basically, it employs a merge function which concatenates values for a duplicate key.

- Create a new map
- Use the values of the old map for the keys to the new
- If the new map does not have a value for the key, put the value in the new map
- Otherwise, concatenate the value to the old value for that key

```
        HashMap<String, String> cities = new HashMap<String, String>();

        cities.put("Manchester", "UK");
        cities.put("London", "UK");
        cities.put("New York", "US");
        cities.put("Chicago", "US");

        Map<String,String> inverted = new HashMap<>();
        for (String key : cities.keySet()) {
            String newKey = cities.get(key);
            String value = inverted.get(newKey);
            if (value == null) {
                inverted.put(newKey, key);
            } else {
                value = value + ", " + key;
                inverted.put(newKey, value);
            }

        }
        for (Entry<String,String> e : inverted.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(e.getKey() + " -> " + e.getValue());
        }
```

It prints

```
UK -> Manchester, London
US -> New York, Chicago
```

Since you didn't specify how to handle duplicate keys.  I could also have stored it in a `Map<String,List<String>>`

Answer (score 0):

As multiple keys can contain the same value, you will have to be able to store multiple values per key in the inversed Map. I recommend using a Set as a value for this.

- Create a map that can save a Set of Strings as values
- Iterate through the original map
- If the country is not found in the new map, create an entry there
- Add the city to the map

This should also work with Java 7 without dependencies.

```
static HashMap<String, Set<String>> inverseMap(HashMap<String,String> map) {
    HashMap<String,Set<String>> inversed=new HashMap<>();
    for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry:map.entrySet()){
        if(!inversed.containsKey(entry.getValue())){
            inversed.put(entry.getValue(),new HashSet<>());
        }
        inversed.get(entry.getValue()).add(entry.getKey());
    }
    return inversed;
}
```

`{Manchester=UK,London=UK}` would turn into `{UK={Manchester,London}}` (order may differ).

Comment: Did you try and compile that?

Comment: I am unable to compile it on my mobile phone.

Comment: Oh, I forgot the `.entrySet()`

Comment: And few closing parens. But not bad for a phone answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
Map<String, String> cities = new HashMap<>();
cities.put("Manchester", "UK");
cities.put("London", "UK");
Map<String, List<String>> reverseMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Entry<String, String> entry : cities.entrySet()) {
     List<String> list = reverseMap.get(entry.getValue());
     if (list == null) {
         list = new ArrayList<>();
         reverseMap.put(entry.getValue(), list);
     }
     list.add(entry.getKey());
}

System.out.println(reverseMap);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can look at MultiMap. It allows mapping of a single key to multiple values.

This is something has been implemented in both Google Guava 
https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

```
ListMultimap<String, String> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
   for (President pres : US_PRESIDENTS_IN_ORDER) {
     multimap.put(pres.firstName(), pres.lastName());
   }
   for (String firstName : multimap.keySet()) {
     List<String> lastNames = multimap.get(firstName);
     out.println(firstName + ": " + lastNames);
   }
... produces output such as:
   Zachary: [Taylor]
   John: [Adams, Adams, Tyler, Kennedy]  // Remember, Quincy!
   George: [Washington, Bush, Bush]
   Grover: [Cleveland, Cleveland]        // Two, non-consecutive terms, rep'ing NJ!
```

As in Apache Commons Collections 
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiValuedMap.html

```
     MultiValuedMap<K, String> map = new MultiValuedHashMap<K, String>();
     map.put(key, "A");
     map.put(key, "B");
     map.put(key, "C");
    Collection<String> coll = map.get(key);
coll will be a collection containing "A", "B", "C".
```

Comment: *// if it can be done without using any special Java 8 feature, that would be great*

Comment: Those libraries are not per se linked to java 8. MultiValuedMap of commons collections is since version 4.1, which requires java 6.  http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/release_4_1.html

Comment: I think dependencies are not a java 8 feature, I think the OP meant streams...

Comment: now I'm confused :) If the aim is to do an own custom implementation, one can simply look into the source code of either.
If the aim is to just get it working, I would be using proven libraries (guava, commons collections)

Answer (score -2):

You can iterate over the entry set of your original map and use the values (country code) as key and add each key (cities) to a list:

```
static HashMap<String, List<String>> inverseMap(HashMap<String, String> map) {
   HashMap<String, List<String>> countryToCity = new HashMap<>();
   for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry: map.entrySet()){
       countryToCity.computeIfAbsent(entry.getValue(), k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(entry.getKey());
   }
   return countryToCity;
}
```

Comment: ComputeIfAbsent is a Java 8 feature.The OP didn't want that.